# Number of Snowflake invocations for external function doesn't match number of rows sent

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an external function in Snowflake:

```
create or replace external function test(value string)
    returns variant
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    api_integration = my_integration
    headers = (
     'method'='<method>')
     MAX_BATCH_ROWS = 100
    as 'https//test/proxy'
;
```

On invoking this `test` external function, I get the following query statistics:

[image]

As you can see the number of rows sent = number of rows received.
There are no `HTTP 5xx errors` nor are there any `Retries due to transient errors`.

The number of rows are 100,000 and I have set the `MAX_BATCH_ROWS=100`.
Thus, the `Total Invocations` should then be 1000, not 1015.

Why are there more invocations to the external function and how do I eliminate these extra calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because MAX_BATCH_ROWS is, as the name suggests, the maximum number of rows per batch that SF will use. The actual number of rows per batch could be any number below that, based on how SF chooses to optimise the function call.